# NgOnInit() Runs after/in parallel with constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

```
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
 this.firestore.collection('settings').doc('settings').valueChanges().subscribe(settings => {
  console.log('getting settings');
  this.settings = settings;
});
}
ngOnInit() {
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
   console.log(this.settings);
  }
}
```

my console output, however, is

undefined

getting settings

How can I make one run after the other? Without putting everything in NgOnInit with whole code going after .then()

**Edit:**
I have edited the code as an answer below suggested

With forkJoin:

```
  ngOnInit() {
forkJoin([this.firestore.collection('settings').doc('settings').valueChanges(),
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams]).subscribe(values => {
  this.settings = values[0];
  console.log('I am a console');
  console.log(this.settings);
  this.queryParams = values[1];
  if (this.queryParams['myParam']) {
    this.setmyParamTrue();
  }
});
```

However, nothings goes to console, with or without any queryParams

Needless to say, I need to retrieve settings from firestore only once and paramters don't have to exist.

Comment: The constructor always triggers first (so before ngOnInit) - however, you're doing async stuff in the constructor and your console is inside the callback so it triggers later. One tip - don't do actual work in the constructor - do that in ngOnInit. To fix this you need to use RxJs operators - like in this case you could either switchMap or use a combineLatest to subscribe to both observables at once.

Comment: I have edited my post. It was actually in constructor jsut to illustrate my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Situation

From your original code:

```js
1  class SomeComponent {
2  
3    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
4      this.firestore.collection().doc().valueChanges().subscribe(settings => {
5        console.log('getting settings');
6        this.settings = settings;
7      });
8    }
9  
10   ngOnInit() {
11     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
12       console.log(this.settings);
13     }
14   }
15 }
```

In the `constructor` on line #4, you are simply creating a [`Subscription`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription).  The logic you pass to the `.subscribe()` method will be executed each time the observable emits a value.

In `ngOnInit` on line #11, you are creating another subscription.

The order in which the callback functions are executed is completely dependent on when each observable emits, NOT when you registered the subscription! (*Obviously in your case the observable from `ActivatedRoute` is emitting first, then later the one from `AngularFireStore`.*)

> NgOnInit() Runs after/in parallel with constructor

Hopefully you can see why this statement is not true!

---

## The Goal

> How can I make one run after the other?

You are trying to access `this.settings` in your callback, but it isn't ready yet!  The solution is to create an observable that begins only once the `settings` value is ready.

Let's define your settings as an observable:

```js
1  class SomeComponent {
2
3    private settings$ = this.firestore.collection().doc().valueChanges();
4    
5    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
6  
7    ngOnInit() {
8      this.settings$.pipe(
9        switchMap(settings => this.route.queryParams.pipe(
10         tap(params => console.log('both values', { settings, params }))
11       ))
12     ).subscribe();
13   }
14 }
```

You see on line #8 we start with `this.setting$` and `pipe` its emissions to [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) which will subscribe to an inner source and emit the source's emissions.  In this case, your inner source is the params observable.

We put a `pipe` on the inner params observable so that [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) would have access to both `settings` and the emitted `params`.

`tap` is useful to execute side effects and is often preferred to putting logic in subscribe callback.

---

Depending on what your purpose is for this subscription inside `ngOnInit`, it can be helpful to also define the observable separately, as we did with `settings$`:

```js
1  class SomeComponent {
2
3    private settings$ = this.firestore.collection().doc().valueChanges();
4    private doWork$ = this.settings$.pipe(
5      switchMap(settings => this.route.queryParams.pipe(
6        tap(params => console.log('both values', { settings, params }))
7      ))
8    );
9
10   constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
11 
12   ngOnInit() {
13     this.doWork$.subscribe();
14   }
15 }
```

Comment: Thasnk you for the thorough reply. 
However, I'm getting a lot of errors with your 2nd code block: From tslint: TS2345: Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.   Type 'Observable<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<unknown>): Observable<unknown>'.
TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable '... Since Ican't really put it in comment, im uploading an image of my ide: https://i.imgur.com/wsiwWDO.png

Comment: Nevermind, have to import switchmap from rxjs/operators, not rxjs-compat/operator/switchmap. However, phpstorm says its deprecated

Comment: Another thing is that, queryParams shouldn't be dependant on settings actually. Yes, one query parameter uses setings, but since settings are used elsewhere in the code as well, me thinks it would make more sense for readabilty and structure, to first get the settings and then parse the query

Comment: I don't know why it would say `switchMap` is deprecated, it's not :-)

Comment: With this code, `queryParams` is NOT dependent on `settings$`; `doWork$` depends on getting settings first, and then uses `queryParams`.  If settings are used elsewhere in the code, you can simply also declare other observables to also begin with `settings$`. (`doWork2$ = settings$.pipe(...)`)

Answer (score 1):

There are two operators which might help you to use 2 observables with each other:

1. forkJoin
2. combineLatest
3. switchMap

In case you need to run it once you have both, use `forkJoin` as below:

```
constructor(
  private firestore: AngularFirestore, 
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
 
  forkJoin([
   this.firestore.collection('settings').doc('settings').valueChanges(),
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams
   ]).subscribe(values => {
      this.settings = values[0]; //<- you'll get settings here
      console.log(values[1]);
      // use the call accordingly.
   })
}
```

Similarly, you can use `combineLatest` if you need to listen continuously.  and also use `switchMap`. Depends on the use case totally.

Comment: I have edited my post